# VsVim: Is there a way to dismiss ReSharper intellisense and stay in insert mode?

Tags: resharper, vsvim

When using VsVim and ReSharper, I type something that brings up the intellisense window. I want to make it go away, so I press the escape key. The intellisense window is gone, but I'm also back in normal mode.

Is there a way to make the intellisense window go away and stay in insert mode?

Comment: I don't know the answer. But the way I'd approach this would be to find if ReSharper has a command to dismiss its suggestions. Then bind it to a key that you prefer (rather than Esc).

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently working on a guide for working with VsVim and Resharper ( https://github.com/keithn/vsvimguide )

One of the little tricks I found for  this situation is to press <kbd>Alt</kbd> then <kbd>Alt</kbd> again and it gets rid of the autocomplete.

What it's actually doing is taking you to the menu bar then takes you back to editing but ditches the autocomplete in the process.